# Replace background image if the url is empty

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

I need to fulfill a `<div>` block with a background image that is retrieved from firebase. I hope that if the image stored on Firebase is empty, then the background should be replaced by a default photo that was stored in a local directory. How should the grammar be like?

```
let pic = 'dir\to\photo.jpg'

<div className="card__header" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${person.backgroundImage[person.backgroundImage.length-1].url})` }}>
```

How can I replace the content of style with `pic` when the image is null?

Comment: You can do something like this `<img class="cc_image" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" style="background-image: url(*your remote image*)"/>`

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is to utilize **2 Background Images**

```
  background-image: url(main.jpg), url(default.jpg);
  background-position: right bottom, left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
```

or in shorthand

```
  background: url(main.jpg) right bottom no-repeat, url(default.jpg) left top repeat;
```

In this example, default.jpg will load first, with main.jpg loading on top of it. If main.jpg doesn't exist, default is still there.

Answer (score 1):

you can add function and check if an image is present

```
setBackgroundImage() {
  let pic = 'your/default/image.jpg';
  let imageUrl = person.backgroundImage[person.backgroundImage.length-1].url;
  if (url != undefined) {
     return imageUrl;
  } else {
     return pic;
  }
}
```

now you can use this function like

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${setBackgroundImage()})'}}></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `person.backgroundImage[person.backgroundImage.length-1].url` returns a falsy value (null, undefined, 0 or empty string) if the image isn't present on firebase.

With that cleared up, we can evaluate a fallback by the `||`(or) operator,

```html
<div className="card__header" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${person.backgroundImage[person.backgroundImage.length-1].url || pic})` }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the default image in the background and set the dynamic image as `<img>` as the child of that block. Whenever the image is not loaded, the default image will be displayed